# Postgre INSERT ON CONFLICT

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

How to achieve the functionality of `INSERT ON CONFLICT` while doing a bulk import with `Binary COPY` in PostgreSQL/Npgsql?

Answer (score 0):

The following will only work if you `COPY` from a file or program on the database server:

- Define a [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) foreign table for the file you want to load.
- Use this foreign table in an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` statement.

With `COPY FROM STDIN` you are out of luck and will have to do it in two steps.